# Is there a tool for .Net that creates a programme / dependency flow chart from IL / source?

Tags: .net, charts, dependencies, flowchart

I am trying to see how a bunch of .Net functions are used throughout a very large project and I would like to visually chart them so I can see the flow from / to each function.

There are only a few functions I want to track so it is not an exhaustive view.

Thanks

Ryan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [nDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) is what you're looking for.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExitingTheZoneOfPainStaticAnalysisWithNDepend.aspx

Answer (score 2):

[Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) has a [plugin](http://www.codeplex.com/reflectoraddins) that maps your [dependencies](http://reflectoraddins.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Graph).